# Python kivy show large amount of data in TreeView

Tags: python, optimization, treeview, kivy

I had run into an optimization problem in Python with Kivy TreeView.
I have large amount of data, nearly 160k items that I want to show inside kivy, using TreeView.

Structure of the tree is like this: `Root -> Groups -> Types -> Items`. Only items are in large amounts. Groups + Types are less than 200.

When loading and showing all `160k` items it was unusable, so I made that, when you click on type inside TreeView, items corresponding to that type are loaded and shown. It cut time on types with less than a few hundred items. When I click on types that hold as much as 8k items it's extremely slow to load and show them.

I'm looking for a better way of doing this preferably using TreeView and Kivy, but open to alternatives. I need to add, that I want to do operations on these items using some GUI.

Custom TreeViewLabel class that I'm using:

```py
class TreeViewFile(TreeViewLabel):

    def __init__(self, big_path=None, name=None, files_info=None, root=None, **kwargs):
        super(TreeViewFile, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._big_path = big_path
        self._files_info = files_info
        self.text = name
        self._root = root

    # On clik, if leaf create TreeViewItem
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if not self.is_leaf:
            self._root.toggle_node(self)
        elif self._files_info is not None:
            for file in self._files_info.keys():
                self._root.add_node(TreeViewItem(file_info=self._files_info[file]), self)
```

### Edit

Looking at the comments I changed my code, so now it uses RecycleView inside TreeView. Loading speed got faster, but the problem with it is that, the RecycleView is scrollable inside a TreeView. It looks weird, but works.

```py
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if not self.is_leaf:
            self._root.toggle_node(self)
        elif self._files_info is not None:
            rv = RV() # RecycleView
            data = []
            for file in self._files_info.keys():
                if isinstance(self._files_info[file][-1], str):
                    data.append(self._files_info[file][-1])
                else:
                    data.append(self._files_info[file][0])
            rv.data = [{'text': x} for x in data]
            self._root.add_node(rv, self)
```

Comment: Can you use `RecycleView`? That is designed specifically for large data sets.

Comment: It sounds like you definitely want to invent a RecycleView-based alternative to the TreeView.